# SLA Milestone Calculator and Case Mass edit

Tags: apex, case, casemilestone

I have a class implemented with the Support.MilestoneTriggerTimeCalculator interface implemented, and it is working as intended. However i'm having an "To many SQL queries" error when i edit more than 40 cases to recalculate the respectives SLA Timers. I believe this to be due to the fact that this interface runs case by case. I want to know if anyone has a workaround for this or something to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a drawback because of this interface definition, as it doesn't allow the list of Cases.

```
global class CaseMilestoneTimeCalculator implements Support.MilestoneTriggerTimeCalculator 
{   
    public CaseMilestoneTimeCalculator(){  
    }       

    global Integer calculateMilestoneTriggerTime(String caseId, String milest)      
    {
        //need to query the SLA defined in Custom setting/Meta data type for respective user or group
    }
}
```

> Workaround could be limit the batch size when you are creating or loading the data below 35 records, in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a condition to the entitlement process to exclude the users running the batch. This way .. each time the batch is run and making (related) updates to the case the milestone time calculator is not called and thus you will not run into these SOQL governor limits.

Comment: Thank you Jos for the answer, but this not apply because the mass edit is indeed what needs to calculate the sla timer. Therefore it's more of a structural problem of the tool (Calculator). My solution was to limit the number of Cases they can edit with each transaction. And plus, if you did that no one would ever be able to run the milestone calculator, rendering the code useless.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution by assigning an auxiliary list in the Case trigger to be through a custom SLA__c field:

Trigger:

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (
before insert, 
before update, 
before delete, 
after insert, 
after update, 
after delete, 
after undelete) {

    if (Trigger.isBefore)
        if (Trigger.isUpdate)
            CaseHandler.getInstance().beforeUpdate();
        else if (Trigger.isInsert)
            CaseHandler.getInstance().beforeInsert();
        else
            CaseHandler.getInstance().beforeDelete();
    else
        if (Trigger.isUpdate)
            CaseHandler.getInstance().afterUpdate();
        else if (Trigger.isInsert)
            CaseHandler.getInstance().afterInsert();
        else
            CaseHandler.getInstance().afterDelete();}
```

Handler:

```
public with sharing class CaseHandler{
private static final CaseHandler instance = new CaseHandler();
private CaseHandler() {}

public static List<Case> lstNewAux;

public static CaseHandler getInstance() {
    return instance;
}    

/**
* Method to handle trigger before update operations. 
*/
public void beforeUpdate() {
    lstNewAux = (List<Case>) Trigger.new;
}

/**
* Method to handle trigger before insert operations. 
*/
public void beforeInsert() {
    lstNewAux = (List<Case>) Trigger.new;
}}
```

Class:

```
  global class MilestoneTimeCalculator implements Support.MilestoneTriggerTimeCalculator{
global Integer calculateMilestoneTriggerTime(String caseId, String milestoneTypeId){
    system.debug('test => ' + CaseHandler.lstNewAux);
    if (CaseTH.lstNewAux != null){
        Map<Id, Case> mapCase = new Map<Id, Case>(CaseTH.lstNewAux);
        Case cs = mapCase.get(caseId);
        return cs.SLA__c.intValue();
    }

    return null;
}}
```

If I was able to help with your problem or if you found another solution, please let me know. :D